# How can I find Android TextView number of characters per word?

Tags: android, string, textview, find, character

How can I find how many characters are there in each word of a TextView in Android. I want to set few words of my TexView to bold type. So for instance if the text view has a text "Happy Coding, Fellow Coders". I would like to set "Coding" & "Coders" to bold type.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. It contains counting words based on the comma, colon or semicolon and dot characters :

```
String str = "Happy Coding, Fellow Coders";
String[] strArr = str.split(",| |.");

Log.e("TAG", "split String: " + strArr);
```

If you want to split only from whitespaces, then use :

```
.split("\\s+") instead of .split(" ")
```

Then you can simply use the loops to count the characters of every words.